# Infinite triangular Resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

A classic problem but I couldn't find the answer I want.

Determine the resistance  between the points A and B of the frame made of thin homogeneous wire (as shown in figure), assuming that the number of successively embedded equilateral triangles (with sides decreasing by half) tends to infinity. Side  is equal to  units and the resistance of unit length of wire is  units.

[image]

I know that this problem can be simplified as:

[image]

and $r$ is the equivalent resistance of $RAB$

What I don't understand is the inner triangle is connected to the middle $AB$, but the simplified version seems to ignore that. Why?

I have searched on Google and nowhere has mentioned why apex of inner triangle can be ignored.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-you-solve-this-question-of-current-and-electricity-for-JEE-Advanced

Comment: Thanks so much. Perfect answer! I couldn’t find it though Google :( the key is symmetry argument :)